# Solr generate key

Tags: solr, indexing

I'm working with solr and indexing data from DB.
When I import the data using SQL query, I got some rows with the same key.
I need a way that solr will generate a new field with unique key.
How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible or not, but maybe you need to re-consider your logic here...

Indexing operation into Solr should be Re-Runable. So, imagine that you come one day and decide to change the schema of your core.

If you generate a new key everytime you import a document, you will end up creating duplicate items when you re-run your data import.

Maybe you need to revisit your DB design to have a unique key, or maybe in the select query, you can create a derived or calculated column value that is calculated based on multiple columns. But I am sure that pushing this problem to solr is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

ideally the unique key should come from the db (are you sure you cannot get one, by composing some columns etc?).

But, if you cannot, Solr supports UUID generation for this, look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey#UUID_techniques) to see how it works depending on your solr version